# Newly append div overlaps in a loop in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to add a new `div` element (`<QuoteContainer>` in my code) in a loop just after the first array item. However, the rest of the array items should adjust styling and not display the new `div`. Here all my `div` are `CSS` components. Also all of them `flex` item.

**Code:**

```
<Chapters>
      {chapters.map((chapter, i) => {
        return (
          <ChapterContainer key={'chapter' + i}>
            <ChapterHeading>{`${chapter.chapter_heading}`}</ChapterHeading>
            <ChapterBody>{`${chapter.chapter_body_text}`}</ChapterBody>
            {i === 0 ? (
              <QuoteContainer display="visible">
                {quote_text}
              </QuoteContainer>
            ) : (
              <QuoteContainer display="none"></QuoteContainer>
            )}
          </ChapterContainer>
        );
      })}
    </Chapters>

 const Chapters = styled.div`
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: right;
 margin-bottom: 67px;
`;

const ChapterContainer = styled.div`
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
height: 180px;
width: 600px;
`;

const ChapterHeading = styled(Body2)``;

const ChapterBody = styled(Body3)`
color: white;
`;

const QuoteContainer = styled.div`
display: flex;
width: 486px;
height: 85.81px;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 67px 0px 67px 0px;
`;
```

**Expected**

```
Heading 1
This is a paragraph 1. 

      "Quote: Time does fly."

Heading 2
This is a paragraph 2.

Heading 3 
This is a paragraph 3.
```

**Problem**
The text where *Quote: Time does fly.* is displayed overlaps on top of the second `div` (Heading 2) and also lot of empty space after the (Heading 2 + Paragraph text) because the div is just hidden there. I need to apply specific styling to the "Quote" which is added after the first `div`.

**Tried**
`flex-grow`, but didn't work.

Comment: Please show the components themselves and the CSS

Comment: Try removing the height you've specified on `ChapterContainer` and let the content define the height

Comment: @ZohirSalak this would still keep a space between the 3rd and 4th `div`. The space is the size of the `QuoteContainer `

Comment: Remove any height you defined on all elements and let content define the size.